# I have an N*M matrix of characters and I'm trying to find the most common character in the whole matrix but instead it's only counting the last row

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to get the most common character from a matrix but instead I'm only getting the most common from the last entered row

```
R = int(input("Enter the number of rows:"))
C = int(input("Enter the number of columns:"))
matrix = []
print("Enter the elements rowwise:")
for i in range(R):
    a=[]
    for j in range(C):
        a.append((input()))
    matrix.append(a)
for i in range(R):
    for j in range(C):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ")
    print()
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(a)
print(count.most_common())
```

output:

```
Enter the number of rows:3
Enter the number of columns:3
Enter the elements rowwise:
a
a
a
e
e
d
c
c
a
a a a 
e e d 
c c a 
[('c', 2), ('a', 1)]
```

Comment: I suggest You put all Your imports at the beginning unless it is necessary to not do that

Comment: Just do `Counter(matrix)` and not `Counter(a)`

Comment: also try this: `count = Counter(matrix)`

Comment: @Onyambu, @Matiiss - Counter will not flatten your multidim lists for you. `Counter(matrix)` would complain about list not being hashable.

Comment: in that case, you will have to do `Counter(sum(matrix, []))`

Comment: What are functions `int` and `input`? They are not base R functions. What packages are you loading? It would be simpler to read the values into a vector with `X <- scan(what="character")`. Then convert to a matrix with `X <- matrix(X, R, C, byrow=TRUE)` and then get the maximum  with `mx <- max(table(X))`. Then `which(table(X)==mx)` tells you which letters are the most common. You do not need a loop to read characters at the console.

Comment: Flatten the matrix using a loop, and then pass the flat matrix to your counter.  See this post for a very active discussion flattening Python lists. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Counter(a)`. When you get the input you do:

```
for i in range(R):
   a=[]
```

so `a` will always be just a single row and be the last row when the for loop ends.

Because `Counter` only counts the outermost iterable, you cannot do `Counter(matrix)`. However, you use a single `Counter` and update it for each row:

```
counts = Counter()
for i in range(R):
   a=[]
   for j in range(C):
       a.append((input()))
   matrix.append(a)
   counts.update(a)
```

Comment: It worked! thank you. I removed the a = [] from the for loop. I'm sorry if the question was not very clear, it's my first time using stack overflow and still learning to code.

Comment: may I ask if I want the output to only show the character without the count what should I modify? the output I'm getting is like [The most common character is: ('A', 10)]. but what if I want the output to be [The most common character is: A]?

Comment: @Ehab651Keeping `a` in the loop is fine, as long as you understand what it means and what it contains after the loop. To get the most common character, you can do `counter.most_common(1)[0][0]` (first `[0]` specifies you have want the first pair in the most common list - watch out, if the counter is empty, this will throw an error; second `[0]` specifies you want the first element of the pair, which will be the actual character).